# Hyperledger network approach

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Taking the following service description:

```
X is a platform matching buyers and sellers.

Buyers can join the platform by creating a buyer account and browse seller shops, buy, manage their account, ..., on the Buyers client application.

Sellers can join the platform by creating a seller account and manage their shops and orders, ..., on the Buyers client application.
```

I am still confuse about the right approach to adopt.

[image]

Here I represented the `organization` X (the platform). I assume that a buyer is not considered as an `organization` but rather a user of X. So every time a buyer create an account, I register a user under X, save email and password on an external database and link this entry to a user in X's wallet.

A seller can be considered as an `organization` (at least to me but happy to debate on that). So every time a seller create an account, I have to create an add a new `organization` to the existing network. They will however share the same "Seller application", also using a email/password approach.

In most of the sample under the Hyperledger Fabric repo, there is like 3-4 `organizations` at the start of the network and it is quite painful to add one more to an existing network. In my case, I could end up with 1 million `organization` or an infinite if the service is a success. Can this scale?

Is it the correct approach for this kind of use case? Any feedback or resource related to this use case is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like a valid use of hyper-ledger fabric. The blockchain is optimized to store transactional information. It isn't a regular DB, if you try, for instance, to store "user profiles" you will have a hard time trying so. For instance, each member for the blockchain network (again, hyper-ledger fabric) is meant to keep a copy of the ledger. Thus, everyone would get access to all user profiles. You can play around with PDC (private data), or as you mention, having virtually infinite users created on a single organization, but that isn't really how it's supposed to be used..

So, again, hyper-ledger fabric is meant to store transactional information (ledger relates to transaction). I think whatever strategy you try to implement for your use case, you should keep buyer/seller profiles/information off chain, and use the ledger only for transactional information that members of the network can see. In this scenario Fabric would server as an audit trail system, adding trust to each operation between buyers/sellers.